# Power BI: advanced query relationships

Tags: microsoft-powerbi, modeling

I need to do left joins in my data model in Power BI. I import my model from SQL Server where I have one big fact table with multiple relationships to dimension tables. Power BI only allows me to do inner joins which allows me to put to my report only one type of fact, when I want to put other type of fact, I would need left join? Someone having same issues or any experiences how to do left joins in Power BI?

Comment: Be more specific and add an example.

Comment: Simple example: I have a Fact table which stores Interest rates, Residual values and Prices on particular business contracts. The fact table itself consist of FkContractId - FK to table Contract, FKCategory - FK to table Category and Value - the value of fact itself. In Category table I have 3 items - Interest Rates = 1, Residual Values = 2 and Price = 3. So FkCategory in Fact table has values from 1 to 3 based on what kind of Category it refers to. I import my simple model to Power BI and want to make report with all types of facts. But I can only join Fact table with Inner Join… Any idea?Thx

Comment: I'm not following the issue - you have Category values 1-3 in both Fact and Dimension tables, so how is a "left join" relevant?

Comment: Imagine I want report with all 3 kinds of value - Interest rates, Residual values and Prices. Once I join Fact table to Contract table and I specify Category of fact = FkCategory = 1, I can display Interest rates. But to display also residual values, I need to join Fact table again, this time with FkCategory = 2..And this is not possible without Left join as when I joined Fact table with FkCategory=1 I had to do INNER JOIN, which limits my final report just to the Facts that have FkCategory = 1. I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from your comments your data is modeled in a Attribute-value pair style. I would create 3 filtered Queries in the Power BI model to split the Fact table data by Category.

With those 3 tables in place in the model, I would create relationships from each Fact-based table to the Contract table. Then Power BI will naturally return all the Interest rates, Residual values and Prices data for each Contract.

Comment: Yes this would solve the problem, the thing is that that my fact table has about 150 000 000 rows and 100 different Categories involved. I could write those queries once, but would it be possible to somehow have it stored and always when I want to create report and I load my Fact table from SQL server this  queries will automatically filter it to 100 small tables? I need to deploy these solution to other users as well. Thxvm

Comment: By Queries I was referring to creating Query objects in the Power Query Editor.  Custom SQL shouldn't be needed. So yes, the Query definitions would be stored in the Power BI file.